# Show $\mathrm{V}(\bar{y}) = \sigma^2/n\cdot (N-n)/(N-1)$

Tags: self-study, variance, sampling, expected-value, proof

How do we show that

$$\mathrm{V}(\bar{y}) = \frac{\sigma^2}{n}\cdot  \frac{(N-n)}{(N-1)}$$

I think this is the sample variance for simple random sampling without replacement.

I have not seen this anywhere but I did manage to find one webpage that kind of mentions it
https://onlinecourses.science.psu.edu/stat506/node/5

But they don't show the proof on there.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Perhaps if you could _define_ what $N$ and $n$ mean? Perhaps saying what values the samples $y_i$ can take on and what the underlying probability model is (choose randomly (without replacement) from the set $\{0,1,2, \ldots,N\}$? or $\{1,2,\ldots, N\}$?)